# How do i search a 2D array within Connect 4 code for a winner?

Tags: arrays, search, 2d

I have an assignment where I am to modify the search for a Connect 4 game.  There is a vertical search given, the instructor states that this is very generic and needs modified, as well as, adding diagonal and horizontal searches to check for a winner.  I've been scouring the net, my books, past assignments to come with a better way to search these ways, and I have nothing.  I have to use the method given.  And ideas are great appreciated.  (Sorry if this is a redundant quetions, I am still fairly new to coding).

// code given to me

```
    protected Player getWinner(Player[][] state, int rowHint, int columnHint) {

    for (int r = 0; r <= GRID_HEIGHT-3; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < GRID_WIDTH; c++) {
                if (
                    state[r][c] != Player.NONE && 
                    state[r][c] == state[r+1][c] &&
                    state[r+1][c] == state[r+2][c]
                ) return state[r][c];
            }
        }    

return Player.NONE;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in the line:

```
state[r][c] != Player.NONE && 
state[r][c] == state[r+1][c] &&
state[r+1][c] == state[r+2][c]
```

Think of these on a graph. Every time you see state[r][c] think of x and y coordinates. r is the y axis and c is the x axis.

The first line initializes an origin and checks to see if the space is taken.
Next line is checking if the origin is equal to the the row above the origin.
Third line does the same as the last, but it checks for the row two above.

To get the horizontal aspect instead of the vertical, simply flip the coordinate addition values:

```
state[r][c] != Player.NONE && 
state[r][c] == state[r][c+1] && //instead of state[r][c] == state[r+1][c] &&
state[r][c+1] == state[r][c+2] //instead of state[r+1][c] == state[r+2][c]
```

To get the diagonal you would basically mix the two together. You'll have to use negative numbers to get the reverse direction as well, but that should give you the right idea.

Comment: That actually helps a lot, very much appreciated!